# What to put in revision section in SBT for Postgres dependency

Tags: postgresql, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

I'm adding a dependency to PostGres 9.6 in the library in my build.sbt file, but I'm unsure of what to put in the revision portion, or what those fields mean:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.6-???-?.jdbc?"
```

I've seen older ones on Stackoverflow such as:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
```

And I know the 9.1 means version 9.1 and the jdbc4 is well... JDBC4. But how do I know what do the other fields mean and where would I get them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc). The correct syntax to use the (current) newest driver:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1"
```

Dont forget to run update

Comment: Thank you, and for clarity, this line in the dependency is for the driver, not for the actual Postgres software itself?

Comment: Sorry, just ran the SBT build with that (and I just installed the latest version of PostGres right before doing this) and it told me `[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: postgresql#postgresql;42.1.1: not found`

Comment: "org.postgresql", not "postgresql". Also I dont think you can install Postgresql (server) using SBT. If you want to run tests and have a postgres available, you can use something like https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded. Apart from that, does not make much sense install the db using sbt...

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear- or I don't understand, this is my first web app/play app. I had just installed Postgresql with Homebrew to my local machine just prior to trying your suggestion (so everything is up to date). EDIT: I'm an idiot, I thought I had copypasta'd your line and clearly I didn't, leaving out the .org on the organization, as you had said.  Thanks again.